# Adding a real with infinite conditions

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Consider the forcing $\Bbb P$ whose conditions are partial functions $p\colon\omega\to2$ with $\operatorname{dom}(p)$ a co-infinite subset of $\omega$, ordered by reverse inclusion.

Does $\Bbb P$ collapse the continuum?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the forcing to add a Prikry-Silver real, discussed on [page 17 of Jech's book Multiple Forcing](https://books.google.com/books?id=qYqEYg6TMScC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=prikry+silver+forcing&source=bl&ots=vts83a-YWY&sig=q4b6vmf78pwOTfN3HWGc2CJwapQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qD3GVI_iJuXIsAT2-ILwCw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=prikry%20silver%20forcing&f=false). A fusion argument shows that it satisfies the countable cover property (every new countable set of ordinals is covered by a ground model countable set), and so it does not collapse the continuum. A Prikry-Silver real is minimal.

Comment: Aha! I knew I'd seen it before. And just as luck would have it, I have a copy of that book from the library with me. I wonder why I didn't check it before!

Comment: Looking at Jech's book it strikes me that we really have two tricks up our sleeve for adding a new subset to some $X$. Fix some ideal on $X$ and forcing with partial functions from $X$ to $2$; either the domains are from the ideal, or the domains are co-positive sets. The ideal of finite sets gives us Cohen in the first case and Prikry-Silver in the latter case.

Comment: I'm sure that it's possible to investigate properties of the new sets inherited from the ideal and the choice of zero or co-positive domains, in a context much more general than ideals on $\omega$ (but I do expect things to get much more complicated, of course... and depend on additional hypotheses like cardinal arithmetics and large cardinals).

Comment: I'd encourage you to go for it! And what of other natural ideals, such as the ideal of all $A\subset\omega$ for which $\sum_{n\in A}\frac1n$ converges, or the ideal of all asymptotic density zero sets?

Comment: Yes, I will definitely give this more thought. But first I really *really* ***really*** gotta finish banging some argument shut about choiceless forcing (and actually the question here is somewhat related to trying some alternative approach in solving the issue I'm dealing with by changing the forcing a bit). I think I'll drag a couple other Ph.D. students with me to these sort of questions.

Comment: Jockusch told me that a similar method (restrict the conditions with the recursive ones) was also used by Spector, and later by Lachlan, to construct minimal Turing degrees.

Comment: @Asaf The generalized Cohen forcing and generalized Silver forcing were introduced by Serge Grigorieff [_Combinatorics on ideals and forcing_](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843%2871%2990011-8), Ann. Math. Logic 3 (1971), 363-394; [MR0297560](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0297560).

Answer (score 14):

While Prikry-Silver forcing satisfies Axiom A and hence does not collapse $\omega_{1}$, it is independent of $MA + \neg CH$ whether Prikry-Silver forcing preserves the continuum. Under $MA + \neg CH$, this question is equivalent to whether the additivity of the Silver ideal is the continuum. So, for example, PFA implies that Prikry-Silver forcing does indeed preserve the continuum. For the corresponding question for Sacks forcing, see:

H. Judah, A. W. Miller and S. Shelah, 
Sacks forcing, Laver forcing, and Martin's axiom. 
Arch. Math. Logic 31 (1992), 145–161.